# Why Mac's Google Drive creates empty folders for DOCX file?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, google-drive, docx

Saving Microsoft Word files (docx) in Google Drive's folder generates many empty folders with a similar name.

This is not user-friendly behavior.

Any idea why does it happen or how to disable it?

I could not understand the pattern of creation. Generally, it creates a new folder on saving, but it won't get removed automatically.

[image]

Comment: I'd avoid it by never saving directly to any type of online sharing/sync solution… but that's just me ;)

Answer (score 0):

stumbled upon this by looking for a solution to the same problem.

Can I ask: **do you happen to be using Mendeley or any other reference manager?**

I do, and upon forcibly deleting these folders from Drive (my Mac's Finder would not let me) I lost all Mendeley's field information in the document. "Lucky me" I only had about 20 references inserted. If I had to retype hundreds of them it would have been plain mental death.

If not a reference manager specifically, perhaps you have another Word plugin installed or activated, that may be causing this problem? I only endured this with this specific Word file and has not happened elsewhere.

Comment: Hi, please use the comment section to ask for additional information.